# How to specified below value from base record query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like this and I need to specify below price than base price in table.

```
id   value   price   base
1     aaa     100    
2     bbb     200    
3     ccc     300    Yes
4     aaa     200    Yes
5     aaa     300
6     aaa     400
```

like this :

```
id   value   price   status
1     aaa     100     down 
2     bbb     200     
3     ccc     300     base
4     aaa     200     base
5     aaa     300     up
6     aaa     400     up
```

With this code I can get max and min price value:

```
SELECT
    min(price) as min_price
    , max(price) as max_price
FROM 
(
    select *
    From MyTable
) tmp;
```

Comment: What is your question here exactly? Also, why the derived table in your attempt to achieve whatever it is you want? You could just do `SELECT MIN(price) AS min_price, MAX(price) AS max_price FROM dbo.MyTable;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the following statement is a possible solution to your problem:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO MyTable
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 'aaa', 100, NULL,  CONVERT(varchar(5), NULL)),
   (2, 'bbb', 200, NULL,  CONVERT(varchar(5), NULL)),
   (3, 'ccc', 300, 'Yes', CONVERT(varchar(5), NULL)),
   (4, 'aaa', 200, 'Yes', CONVERT(varchar(5), NULL)),
   (5, 'aaa', 300, NULL,  CONVERT(varchar(5), NULL)),
   (6, 'aaa', 400, NULL,  CONVERT(varchar(5), NULL))
) v (id, value, price, base, status)
```

SELECT statement:

```
SELECT 
   id,
   value,
   price,
   base,
   CASE
      WHEN base = 'Yes' THEN 'base'
      WHEN price < MAX(CASE WHEN base = 'Yes' THEN price END) OVER (PARTITION BY value) THEN 'down'
      WHEN price > MAX(CASE WHEN base = 'Yes' THEN price END) OVER (PARTITION BY value) THEN 'up'
   END AS status
FROM MyTable
ORDER By id
```

UPDATE statement:

```
; WITH cte AS (
   SELECT 
      id,
      value,
      price,
      base,
      status,
      CASE
         WHEN base = 'Yes' THEN 'base'
         WHEN price < MAX(CASE WHEN base = 'Yes' THEN price END) OVER (PARTITION BY value) THEN 'down'
         WHEN price > MAX(CASE WHEN base = 'Yes' THEN price END) OVER (PARTITION BY value) THEN 'up'
      END AS status2
   FROM MyTable
)
UPDATE cte
SET status = status2
```

Result:

```
id value price base status
--------------------------
1  aaa   100        down
2  bbb   200    
3  ccc   300   Yes  base
4  aaa   200   Yes  base
5  aaa   300        up
6  aaa   400        up
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , can you tell me how can use this code to update status value in table ?

Comment: I try but give an error 'Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.'

Comment: @HadiRanji, you can't use a window function directly in an assignment (`UPDATE ... SET ...`), so you need to use a CTE.